# how to return several FileField from Queryset in Django?

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset, filefield

I have a models with FileField for videos.

When i upload only one video i **can** return it with this code in the **view.py**:

```
def cours(request, id, slug):
    c = Cours.objects.get(id=id, slug=slug)
    p = Plan_simple.objects.get(cours=c)
    return render(request, 'upload/cours.html', locals())
```

**But** when i upload two or more videos whith formset, and i change get fuction by filter it doesn't work:

```
def cours(request, id, slug):
    c = Cours.objects.get(id=id, slug=slug)
    p = Plan_simple.objects.filter(cours=c)
    return render(request, 'upload/cours.html', locals())
```

the **models.py**

```
class Cours(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de parution")
    categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.titre)
        super(Cours, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "cours"
        db_table = "cours"
        ordering = ['date']

class Plan_simple(models.Model):
    partie = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de parution")
    vid = models.FileField(upload_to='file/', blank=True, null = True)
    cours = models.ForeignKey(Cours, related_name = "plan_simple", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.partie    

    class Meta:
        db_table = "plan_simple"
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line. It does not request anything from the database. It only specifies a filter.

```py
p = Plan_simple.objects.filter(cours=c)
```

You should change it to this...

```py
p = Plan_simple.objects.filter(cours=c).all()
```